# Pipe all bash output to a script?

Tags: linux, bash

Here's my issue. I found a hilarious little tool [`lolcat`](https://github.com/busyloop/lolcat) that I want to prank my friend with.

Is there any way I can get all bash `stdout` to pipe thru to the program `lolcat`?

Some examples:

```
$ git status
```

When submitted, becomes this command behind the scenes:

```
$ git status | lolcat --force
```

Basically I want any program output from bash to go thru `lolcat`.

I can easily inject the program into a `ps1` prompt, but I wanted to one up that and really make it hilarious.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: You really need to get out more having a prank with a bit of software with your friend!

Comment: You probably need to convince `bash` that its output (and input) are going to a terminal (rather than a pipe).  You might have to investigate using a pseudo-tty (`pty`) instead of a pipe, like the `expect` program does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following

```
bash | lolcat
```

However with my minimal testing it shows the ansi escape codes and the prompt isn't colored.

Comment: I put this in `bashrc` file. When I use it in Ubuntu, it wouldn't let me type any commands.

Comment: ALERT. If you put that in your bashrc, then you should actually get infinite recursion! bashrc is called every time bash runs, and if bashrc calls bash, it never ends! PS: `bash | lolcat` works fine for me. Colored prompt. Everything else appears in rainbow. The order of output is often jumbled, though.

Comment: Agreed about not putting this in `bashrc`.

Comment: to break recursion you can add the line at the end of the bashrc with --rcfile flag. e.g.
bash --rcfile "" | egrep --color 'FAIL|failed'